# Design Pattern to be used for supporting different filter set on a student relational table in Java

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns, querydsl

I have a SQL table with schema

[student_id, standard, home_city, home_state, country, num_of_subjects]

Now, I want to support api end point over this table as below:

```
GET /students?home_state=?&country=?&home_city=?&standard=?
```

All the filters are optional.

Now, I want to know a good code design for this requirement. For technology I am using Java for web-app and a library querydsl for runtime query construction.

I have some ideas floating, but I'm looking for a concrete and extensible approach which can handle cases, so when a new filter column is added (let us say fav_subject), it should require minimum code changes.

For ideas, I am thinking of a Filter interface with a method

```
public interface Filter { 
   // If apiCallParameters contains this filter key, add filter to addToList
   void addFilter(Map<String, String> apiCallParameters, List<QueryFilters> addToList);
}
```

All possible filters will be a class each, implementing this interface. Now, the query construction class can have `List<Filter>`, with each having addFilter deciding whether this filter will be added or not.

I want to better understand how this seemingly very common case is handled in code design.

Answer (score -1):

The api you are describing maps to a REST interface.  If you are looking for that kind of interface you could write something along these lines:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;

@Service
@Path("/students")
public class StudentResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public JSONObject getStudent(@Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                                 @ApiParam(required = false) @PathParam("home_state")String homeState,
                                 @ApiParam(required = false) @PathParam("home_city")String homeCity,
                                 @ApiParam(required = false) @PathParam("country")String country,
                                 @ApiParam(required = false) @PathParam("standard")String standard) 
    {

        // Do what you will with these strings which may be empty.
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject;

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just the api end point you have written, I am interested in the story that goes between this end point and database layer